# Access twitter data without using the API

Tags: java, api, twitter, bigdata

First time here!

I want to ask you if it's possible to access twitter information (I only want to read) like users, hashtags, twets... without using the twitter API.

I have looked into the API, and I kind of don't like what I find ... I want to do a lot of connections because I want my users to refresh or do query a lot of times, and the restrictions of twitter are Strong...

For example: I would like to enable my users to search for a hashtag, and 2 secs later search for  user tweets... and possibly by many app users ... i would like to make a twitter analyzer (not exactly that, but just to make you to understand what i want)

Do you think I will get restrictions from twitter for this app?Will I overload the limits? I have never tried it and I don't know how it works.

Thank you all!

Comment: Thanks for the corrections, I'm not an English native :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to do this without using either Twitter's api or someone elses.  If you don't like what Twitter provides you might look into other providers like Topsy http://topsy.com/. There are numerous others.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look.